Teacher Summit or Teachers' Summit
We're putting on an event and calling it - NNJ Teacher Summit. However, there is a debate on whether it should be Teachers' Summit. As a title of an event, do we need the "s"?

Teachers' Summit is unpronounceable, so there's that. And there are no cars' dealers or appliances' stores.

Perhaps you can find other questions here that cover this.  Something like "shoe store" or "shoes store" ... "sport complex" or "sports complex".  I think there is no rule for this.

This question is similar to: When are attributive nouns plural?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. There is another duplicate, more obviously related to the particular example here....

A really good overview is given over on ELL by john c. j., at 'image directory' or 'images directory' ... pluralizing of attributive nouns. See also Why do we say a hotel room and not a hotel's room for the choice between Saxon genitive and attributive noun.

Also, ...possessives ... -should-this be'the standard University Center’s assessment battery' or 'the standard University Center assessment battery'? and Attributive or Possessive noun: the Dell Company's staff. or the Dell Company staff?

@Yosef Baskin We manage Sports Centre.
